# jquery ajax retrieve value from plain/text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm stuck with following problem.

A page requests user and password. If an user and his password exists, the page outputs just a plain 1. Otherwise a 0.

How do I check this with jquery ajax and process it further depending on the output?

```
$(function () {

$("#checkCode").click(function () {

    var var_pCode = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbPartner").val();
    var var_cCode = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbCode").val();
    var myResult


    $.ajax({
        url: "codeValidator.aspx",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { pCode: var_pCode, cCode: var_cCode }
    }).done(function (msg) {
        //alert(msg);
        if (msg = "1") { alert('111'); }
        else {alert('000')}
    });


});
```

});

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net we have to do msg.d try this. Secondly you are missing the webmethod name in url. The is a nice example you calling server side method by [jquery ajax with asp.net](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

```
$.ajax({
        url: "codeValidator.aspx/SomeStaticWebMethodOfServerSide",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { pCode: var_pCode, cCode: var_cCode }
    }).done(function (msg) {
        //alert(msg);
        if (msg.d == "1") { alert('111'); }
        else {alert('000')}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an assignment in your if statement.

It should be

```
if ("1" == msg) {  }
```